# Getting error while reading contacts in android development

Tags: android

I'm new to android development. I'm developing in eclipse and java.   I'm trying to read contacts and do some string manupulation like substring() or contains ().   i did the following steps,

1. Permission added (  )
2. Code to read contacts :

   ```
   Cursor people=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
   while(people.moveToNext())
   {
          int id=people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
      String name= people.getString(id);
   if(name!="")
   {
       edittext1.setText(name.substring(2,3));
   }
   }
   ```

Here i'm getting error because of substring.  I'm getting error if i use any string class methods.    But if assign some hardcoded value in name,then i'm not getting any error. ie.

```
       String name= "John";  // people.getString(id);
```

Error messages :

```
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1111, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.ravi.vrs/com.ravi.vrs.Voice}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2553)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2595)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:121)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at com.ravi.vrs.Voice.onActivityResult(Voice.java:71)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2549)
08-19 22:13:03.467: E/AndroidRuntime(4265):     ... 11 more
```

Could anyone please guide me how to fix this issue ?

Comment: what is line 71 `Voice.java` is your edittext initialized?

Comment: Please post your Voice.onActivityResult method.

Comment: The exception is being thrown from the `onActivityResult` method of your `Voice` class. Please post that entire method and indicate which is line 71. Also, you should not use `name!=""` to test for string (in)equality because `==` and `!=` test for object identity, not equality of string values. Always use the `equals()` method to compare strings (e.g.,: `!"".equals(name)`) or (perhaps closer to what you need) `(name != null && name.length() > 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the code fragment you posted is from the `onActivityResult` method of class `Voice`. The problem is probably due to a contact not having a defined `DISPLAY_NAME`, in which case `name` will be set to `null`. You are not checking for a null value for `name`. Change your code from this:

```
if (name!="")
```

to:

```
if (name != null && name.length() > 0)
```

You should also be protecting against exceptions when you call `getString`. From [the docs for `Cursor.getString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29):

> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write the result of `people.getString(1)` to logcat, because I guess it's null. 
Look at `ResultInfo{who=null, ...}`

Cheers